Have the cursor in the beginning of the replacement string post find-substitute
The commnad:
:s/foo/&bar

when applied to a line containing foo, catches it and append bar on it, then user hits Enter, the cursor immediately gets into very beginning of the line.
How to let it get into the beginning of the bar string instead, while it must consistently be correct, regardless the foo string is in the mid of the line, or the foo string at very beginning of the line?

I took the freedom to reformulate your quesrion. Feel free to revert my changes if I have misunderstood it :-)

IMHO, it's best to get used to the default behavior. and :substitute works on lines. It depends on the actual line but most of the time you will only need to follow up with fb to move the cursor to "bar".

Agreed @Friedrich: what’s the behavior going to be with a range?

I would do substitute this way:
:s/foo\zs/bar

Where \zs defines the start of the part of the pattern that will be replaced.
More I formation with :help /\zs
Then I would hit n to reposition the cursor on bar (or /Enter which is equivalent)

In the same idea, if we use &, we can search with //e+1 (yes, double slash -> empty pattern == last pattern)

unfortunately still confused on having it duplicated;
:s/foo\zs/&
can' work as it seems foo not visible by & scope now
have tangible idea and solution?

I'm not sure I follow you :-|. Why do you do :s/foo\zs/& and not :s/foo\zs/bar as proposed (the & is not necessary anymore since the replacement doesn't have to replace the foo anymore)?

that's why said, shoul be discussed, opened in new question?

Maybe better to have a new question to avoid confusion :-)

asking now but even some prerequisite before said;
on having it duplicated; :s/foo\zs/& can' work
